Why do I encounter no such file or directory in my s3 script
I tried running the script but encountering error
import os
import boto3

# Create an S3 client
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

# Set the bucket name
bucket_name = 'heavyclick'

# Function to upload a directory recursively
def upload_directory(directory_path, bucket_name, prefix):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory_path):
        for file in files:
            local_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            relative_path = os.path.relpath(local_path, directory_path)
            s3_path = os.path.join(prefix, relative_path)
            upload_file(local_path, bucket_name, s3_path)

# Function to upload a single file
def upload_file(local_path, bucket_name, s3_path):
    try:
        s3.upload_file(local_path, bucket_name, s3_path)
        print("Uploaded {} to {}".format(local_path, os.path.join("s3:/", bucket_name, s3_path)))
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error uploading {}: {}".format(local_path, str(e)))

# Get the current working directory
current_dir = os.getcwd()

# Upload the gpt-2 and bert directories
upload_directory(os.path.join(current_dir, 'gpt-2'), bucket_name, 'gpt-2')
upload_directory(os.path.join(current_dir, 'bert'), bucket_name, 'bert')

I tried running and rewrite to fix it even downgrading still faced error
(env) macbook@Macbooks-MacBook-Pro marketing-automation % python s3_uploader.py
/Users/macbook/marketing-automation/env/bin/python: can't open file '/Users/macbook/Desktop/marketing-automation/s3_uploader.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory


So, if you are sure that the file is in /Users/macbook/Desktop/marketing-automation/ then it may be a permissions issue. But basically, the error is telling you what is wrong: it cannot open the file at /Users/macbook/Desktop/marketing-automation/s3_uploader.py, so your script doesn't even execute. this error is coming from the interpreter trying to find the script

What does ls -l s3_uploader.py in that same folder result in?

Thanks! I found out it was because I named the file wrongly and was running a different script, I ran s3_uploader.py instead of s3_upload.py
